# Does real estate investment Trusts (REITS) include non rent producing assets?

Tags: real-estate, reit

Hey I am new to learning about REITS . REITS include office buildings, shopping malls, apartments, hotels, resorts, self-storage facilities, warehouses, and mortgages or loans. But can it buy out land thinking that it's price will soar up in the future even though the land is not to be leased to obtain rent?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything forbidding them from doing so, but that isn't part of their core mission, which is to be an income-producing investment rather than a growth investment.

Read the prospectus for the one(s) you are interested in. That should spell out pretty clearly what they do and don't invest in.